# PHP Image Uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a website, where one of the options that a user gets is to change their avatar.

I would like to know if there is anything that I *shouldn't* or *should* be doing... So here is what I've got.

Here is my PHP file that handles uploads:

```
<?php include('./config.php');
    $user = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $hash = randHash();

    $tempUser = './assets/temp/faces/' .$user. '/';
    $tempUpload = $tempUser . $hash. '/';

    while(is_dir($tempUpload)) {
        $hash = randHash();
        $tempUpload = $tempUser . $hash. '/';
    }

    mkdir($tempUser);
    mkdir($tempUpload);

    $tempFile = $tempUpload . basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);

    $fileType = pathinfo($tempFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileName = $hash;
    $fileName .= '.' .$fileType;

    if($_FILES['avatar']['name']) {
        if(
        $_FILES['avatar']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
        || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
        || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] == 'image/png'
        || $_FILES['avatar']['type'] == 'image/gif'
        ) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $tempFile)) {
                rename($tempFile, $tempUpload . $fileName);
                $tempFile = $tempUpload . $fileName;

                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tempFile);
                if($width > 400 || $height > 400) {
                    unlink($tempFile);
                    rmdir($tempUpload);
                    rmdir($tempUser);
                    echo 'error:004';
                } else {
                    if(!is_dir('./assets/faces/' .$user. '/')) {
                        mkdir('./assets/faces/' .$user. '/');
                    };
                    rename($tempFile, './assets/faces/' .$user. '/' .$fileName);
                    rmdir($tempUpload);
                    rmdir($tempUser);
                    $file = './assets/faces/' .$user. '/' .$fileName;
                    echo $file;

                    $get = $users->prepare("SELECT userAvatar FROM userDetails WHERE userID=?");
                    $get->bind_param('i', $user);
                    $get->execute();
                    $get->bind_result($oldFile);
                    $get->fetch();
                    $get->close();

                    if($oldFile != "./assets/faces/default-face.png") { unlink($oldFile); }

                    $put = $users->prepare("UPDATE userDetails SET userAvatar=? WHERE userID=?");
                    $put->bind_param('si', $file,$user);
                    $put->execute();
                    $put->close();
                }
            } else {
                rmdir($tempUpload);
                echo 'error:003';
            };
        } else {
            rmdir($tempUpload);
            echo 'error:002';
        };
    } else {
        rmdir($tempUpload);
        echo 'error:001';
    };
?>
```

Here is the HTML/Ajax that handles the form:

```
<div class="grp-con mrg-top-med">
    <p class="title">Avatar</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="mrg-rgt-med"><img class="face-preview-lrg" src="<?php echo $userFace; ?>" /></li>
        <li>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#avatar').on('submit', function(e) {
                        var form = $(this);
                        var avatar = form.children('input[type=file]');
                        var btn = form.children('button[type=submit]');
                        var fd = new FormData();
                        fd.append('avatar', avatar[0].files[0]);

                        btn.prepend('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> ');

                        $.ajax({
                            url:'./user-update-avatar.php',
                            data:fd,
                            processData:false,
                            contentType:false,
                            type:'POST'
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            if(data.indexOf('error') != -1) {
                                btn
                                    .removeAttr('class')
                                    .addClass('btn-danger mrg-top-med')
                                    .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>');
                            } else {
                                btn
                                    .removeAttr('class')
                                    .addClass('btn-success mrg-top-med')
                                    .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>');
                                $('.face-preview-lrg').attr('src', data);
                            };
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                btn
                                    .removeAttr('class')
                                    .addClass('btn-seagreen mrg-top-med')
                                    .html('Change Avatar');
                            }, 2000);
                        })
                        .fail(function(data) {
                            btn
                                .removeAttr('class')
                                .addClass('btn-danger mrg-top-med')
                                .html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>');
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                btn
                                    .removeAttr('class')
                                    .addClass('btn-seagreen mrg-top-med')
                                    .html('Change Avatar');
                            }, 2000);
                        });

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                })
            </script>
            <form id="avatar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p>No larger than 400x400</p>
                <input name="avatar" type="file" required />
                <button class="btn-seagreen mrg-top-med" type="submit">Change Avatar</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Return/Exit early**

When validating things, it's always good to handle the exceptional cases first. With your current code, it's hard to see what actually happens in the else case, or the other way around: it's hard to see which else closes which if.

You could reduce the level of nesting you have, and increase readability, by writing it like this:

```
if(!$_FILES['avatar']['name']) { 
    rmdir($tempUpload);
    echo 'error:001';
    // return/exit
}

if($_FILES['avatar']['type'] !== 'image/jpeg'
    && $_FILES['avatar']['type'] !== 'image/jpg'
    && $_FILES['avatar']['type'] !== 'image/png'
    && $_FILES['avatar']['type'] !== 'image/gif'
    ) {
    rmdir($tempUpload);
    echo 'error:002';
    // return/exit
}

// upload
```

**Separating code into blocks**

Your code does a lot in one block. It uploads an image, it validates data, saves data in the database, prints data, etc. This makes your code hard to read, hard to maintain, hard to test, and hard to reuse. Think about creating different methods and classes for the different functionality.

**Handling Directories and moving files**

You have quite a lot of code handling directories. Why are you creating a temporary directory when you don't even know yet if you can upload to it, just to remove it again? It would be easier to just create it once you know that it's actually needed.

You also move the uploaded file around a lot. It first goes to `$tempFile`, then to `$tempUpload . $fileName`, until it finally is saved in the actual directory. The first move seems unnecessary and is also extremely confusing (you move `tempFile`, and then change the `$tempfile` variable to the new location), and the second move should also be easy to avoid by first retrieving the old file.